# JSF 2 - Dynamically added component's ids are not retained on postback

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, state-saving

I have a facet within a component within which i add components dynamically using

```
    UIComponent c = new UICustomComponent();
    c.setId("someIdGeneratedDynamically");
    facet.getChildren().add(c);
```

But on postback, when i iterate over this list, i realize that the components are present but their ids are different from the ones i specified earlier. (more specifically, these ids are of the form "j_id9, j_id10" etc)

I debugged a bit of code in StateManagementStrategyImpl and realized that they are deliberately not storing the component ids while saving the view.

My question is, why doesn't JSF store the component id?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question stated at the end: in RestoreView phase, JSF rebuilds requested view from the template file(s). It is assumed components always receive the same ids as long as the templates don't change. The state is saved using clientIds as keys. If you modified the clientId programmatically it would be impossible to restore the state properly: the recreated component would have the original id and its state would be stored under another (modified) id. That's why it doesn't "store" clientId, it's that thing that's expected to remain constant and allows matching the recreated component with its state from the previous request.

I believe this behavior applies only to components created from the templates. JSF has a dedicated mechanism to handle programmatically added components and I would expect this mechanism to deal with clientIds as expected.

Comment: um, not quite. dynamically added components DO have their client ids saved. See `ComponentStruct` in `StateManagementStrategyImpl`. my question was about component ids and not client ids.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote: dynamically added components use separate mechanism for state management but I understood your question concerned the general mechanism. Client id is a derivative of component id.

Comment: regardless of component ids or client ids, none of them are retained on the next request on the component instance. the client id is just used for restoring the state (as a key in the map), but thats probably the only thing it is used for.

Comment: Client ids are used to match posted data (submitted by browser) with components on the server side and it is crucial they are restored properly. Unfortunately I don't know why it does not happen in your case.

Comment: true. my assumption is that jsf assumes it will automatically assign component ids to those dynamic components and not rely on the user to set them on it. i guess it works for most people because, initially, if it had assigned the ids, then on postback too those components will have the same ids on them i.e j_id1 etc. and therefore decodes would work. but unfortunately, when ids are manually assigned, things are different.